# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many pattern letters: m

Tags: java, string, postgresql, datetime

I try to convert this string to java LocalDateTime

```
String str = "2016-09-29 09:54:27.850373"

                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.mmmmmm");
                configActivityLog.activityTimeStamp = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

but I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many pattern letters: m
```

Comment: `ss` are seconds, not milliseconds. The [`S`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) stands for milliseconds.

Comment: still not working. how to fix?

Comment: Try `ssSSS` instead (seconds can have up to 2 digits, milliseconds up to 3). The rest, i.e. `373` in your example, will be ignored since Java can't represent nano-precision dates.

Comment: try `HH:mm:ss.SSSSS`

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");` this work for me

Comment: Also note that the JavaDoc states that the number of letters isn't relevant for parsing unless it is needed to distinguish between adjacent fields. Thus `...:s.S` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `s` stands for seconds, while `S` stands for fractions of a second, see [*Patterns for Formatting and Parsing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

See a [sample working demo](https://ideone.com/jPeRUg):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String str = "2016-09-29 09:54:27.850373";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter));
    }
}
```